# Query to invoke a function - Access 2003 vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a function in a module (the function combines 6 tables into a new one, then looks up another table to update one of the field values in the new table) and all is working perfectly well. Now I would like to call this function from an access 2003 query so that when i run the query the New Table should be opened.

I tried using Expr: in the query but although the new table is being created in the 'Tables' Section (by invoking my function), all I can see when i run the query is a blank table with one column named 'Expr'.
Can anyone please guide me to the right direction?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is always a good idea to post a little code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in your select ..

```
SELECT * INTO TBL_ALLTABLES
FROM (
--Here your select union all tables for example
SELECT * from tbl1 
UNION ALL
SELECT * from tbl2
UNION ALL
SELECT * from tbl3
UNION ALL
SELECT * from tbl5
UNION ALL
)
```